# Delphi "Not" Operator returns incorrect

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

This code is used to resolve whether an editor should be read only or not.

Code Snippit

```
var
TempBool : Boolean;
begin
      TempBool := (fCurrentSelectedItem as TMyCustomObject).CanEdit; //Check whether this object can be edited; TempBool resolves to True
      TempBool := not(TempBool); // Toggle the Boolean value; !!-- TempBool still resolves to True
      curredtEach.properties.ReadOnly := TempBool; // Set the read only property on the editor
end;
```

TempBool resolves to integer as follows

```
      // Integer(TempBool) = 0
      TempBool := (fCurrentSelectedItem as TMyCustomObject).CanEdit; 
      // Integer(TempBool) = -1
      TempBool := not(TempBool); 
      // Integer(TempBool) = -2
```

Found this [link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsbooleanshortcircuitevaluation_xml.html)  but that didnt help.

Delphi version - XE5

OS - Windows 8.1

After digging around in the 3rd party code I put together this example to demonstrate how the problem can be replicated.

```
program TestLongBool;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Variants;

var
  Val: Boolean;
  Temp: Boolean;
  CanEdit: Boolean;

begin
  try
    Byte (Val) := 255;
    // Val resolves to  True | Integer(Val) = -1
    CanEdit := Val;
    // CanEdit resolves to True
    Temp := not CanEdit;
    // Temp is true when expected false | Integer(Temp) = -2
    if Temp then begin
      WriteLn ('Expected false');
    end;
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      WriteLn (E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      ReadLn;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: How have you determined that the problem is that the `not` operator is not working? It seems far more likely that either `CanEdit` is not returning the result you expect, or if you're debugging, that you're debugging with optimizations enabled (meaning `TempBool` might immediately have been assigned the result of `not((fCurrentSelectedItem as TMyCustomObject).CanEdit)`, instead of being assigned to twice).

Comment: The `not` operator is known to work correctly. You have mis-diagnosed your problem. It is much more prosaic than that. As a general rule, you aren't going to find compiler errors with fundamentals like logical operators.

Comment: Ok so tell me where I went wrong here then, I run the application in debug mode put a break point on the first begin and watch the local variables as I step each line, TempBool starts off False, get switched to true in the 1st line and then doesnt change again?

Comment: @MartynA What's wrong with it is that there is no reproduction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Ah, ok, I didn't try myself, seeing who else is on the case, as it were.

Comment: @user571234 You'll need to tell us all about how `CanEdit` returns a value of `-1` which is certainly not a `Boolean`. However, Stefan's answer explains why you see this behaviour.

Comment: Just in case ... what happens if you write it **without** the parentheses: `TempBool := not TempBool;` ?

Comment: @JensG The compiler removes the spurious parens. You can write it like this if you like `(not (((TempBool))))` and it's all the same

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: some boolean types use -1 ($FFFFFFFF) for `true`, see docs. I think the real question is how `CanEdit` is defined and what it really returns. - What if he has a function `&not()` in his code?

Comment: @JensG `TempBool` is typed as `Boolean`. The compiler understands the other boolean types and will perform the assignment correctly. If he has a function called `&not` in his program, then `not(TempBool)` will still refer to the operator.

Comment: The value of CanEdit is determined by a previous call to TypInfo.GetPropValue

I.E. it starts off as a variant

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: correct, checked and confirmed.

Comment: I do not have have any function called "not" in any of my code

Comment: Of course there is no `not` in your code. Still you won't show what `CanEdit` does. Why not? Also, what is `Boolean` in your code. No 8 bit bit pattern stuffed into a `Boolean` results in `Integer(b)` being -1. Have you re-defined `Boolean`? Why are we having to guess what you have done? Why don't we have a complete program?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes the problem appears to be the way the the original value of CanEdit was determined. System.TypInfo.GetPropValue returns a variant type, cast as a boolean type.

Comment: Not that `Integer(TempBool) = -1` can never happen when `TempBool` is the one byte enumerated type. Again, the facts that you report don't add up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for not showing the code, fCurrentSelectedItem is an instance of a derived TROComplexType class (remobjects). Some way down the call stack is a call to TypInfo.GetPropValue, which appears to be the problem. Still don't know how to fix it, so that CanEdit actually has a value of 1 (True), not -1 (True).

Comment: If you refuse to show any code, then don't expect anybody to tell you how to fix it. Once again, if `b` is of type `Boolean`, then `Integer(b)` can never be `-1`.

Comment: It can if somewhere you did a wrong cast from LongBool to Boolean because for LongBool True is -1.

Comment: @StefanGlienke A boolean is a single byte. So, `Integer(b)` can never equal `-1`. It is always a value in the range `0` to `255`. For it to be `-1` it would need 32 bits set to `1`, but since there are only 8 bits in a Boolean, it always falls short.  http://pastebin.com/ecK3MFHw

Comment: It can because the registers used there are mapped to the least significant byte of the 4 byte register (like AL for EAX, BL for EBX, and so on).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not that I don't want to show the code, the code is external third party Remobjects code.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you'll be able to work out how to fix it. In the meantime, perhaps you might like to get your facts straight. `Integer(b)` can never be `-1`.

Comment: @StefanGlienke The compiler zeros the registers before moving the single byte into the register. It zero extends. My pastebin demonstrates that. Try running it. Perhaps I made a mistake. I don't think so, but maybe I did.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I think you nailed it. The original value must have been a LongBool serialized by the Remobjects SDK.
I'm going to make a small test case and see if this is the root of the problem.

Comment: The compiler knows the difference between `Boolean` and `LongBool`, and knows how to put them into variants, and retrieve them. Clearly something funky is going on, but so long as you stay within the type system, and use variants in the natural way, nothing like this should go wrong. You do need to dig into the code some more, but straight assignments between `Boolean`, `LongBool` and `Variant` won't go awry in this way.

Comment: I just tried: TempBool : LongBool;
and it works?

Comment: Of course, because for LongBool -1 is a "correct" True and the code generated for TempBool := not TempBool is different than the one for TempBool being Boolean.

Comment: @user571234 You aren't trying to understand anything here. You are just trying things at random. If you are happy with that fine, keep trying out random things until you find something that seems to work. I wouldn't do that personally. I'd try to understand. We can help you understand, but only if you give us hard and accurate facts.

Comment: This leads me to believe that the System.TypInfo.SetPropValue method is taking a LongBool variant value, and setting a boolean property of a class instance incorrectly. Surely the method should convert the LongBool to the Delphi boolean equivalent. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, you've certainly missed something. Some code. Seriously, good luck working this out for yourself. On the other hand, if you spent the time to show some code, a complete compilable example, then any one of us will be delighted to explain and help.

Comment: Check what varType your Variant has (`TVarData(myVar).VType`). It should be 11 (varBoolean). Then SetPropValue does the correct handling of mapping -1 to 1 (see the source comment in the code in System.TypInfo). But even if the varType is not varBoolean it should normally raise a RangeError in the nested routine `RangedValue` if you are trying to put -1 into it.

Comment: "*fCurrentSelectedItem is an instance of a derived TROComplexType class (remobjects).*"  -  [TROComplexType](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/TROComplexType_Class) does not offer a `CanEdit` method/property. So it must be within `TMyCustomObject`, right? Can you show *that* code?

Comment: Your edit is bizarre. Still you insist that `Integer(Val)` is `-1` in the face of all the evidence. In fact, `Integer(Val)` is `255`. Anyway, you don't seem to want to learn anything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the watch list I see Integer(Val) = -1 , Byte(Val) = 255
Just showing it as I see it in IDE.

Comment: The debugger is wrong. `Writeln(Integer(Val));` shows the correct value.

Comment: No need to put any code in there - looking at the register shows the correct value. Also I am pretty sure the debugger has no problem with a simple hardcast of Boolean into Integer. You should debug into the CanEdit method and trace the origin of that wrong value. Showing code that artificially creates a wrong value does not help in any way.

Comment: @StefanGlienke You mean you think that the debugger is right, but the compiler is wrong? In the face of all evidence, you continue with this belief that `Integer(b)` can be outside the range `0..255`? Or am I misunderstanding you.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Yes thank you i have traced all the way into CanEdit and deep into the third party sources and have found and patched the problem, just goes to show how third party sources can trip you up.

Comment: And what exactly was the problem in the third party sources I wonder?@David Neither are wrong but you obviously can produce code that leads to such behavior (anyway I have seen both fail at times so claiming they are never working wrong is a bold statement so to say). And yes of course it can be outside of the range of a byte because on x86 you are dealing with 32bit registers and a mostly 32bit aligned stack. So of course it can happen (though very rare and most likely due to some hacky code) to be in the range of Integer.

Comment: @Stefan Nope. `Integer(b)` is always in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: This is even more weird than I imagined. If it is the 3rdparty code I'd recommend a bug report. Either way, don't try this at home, kids!

Comment: @David: fully agreed. If `b` is a Boolean, `Integer(b)` can only return values in the range 0..255. So I guess the code given is not the exact code and `LongBool` is used.

Comment: @Rudy Integer(b) was being evaluated by the debugger. Stefan appears to be very confused here.

Comment: @David: yes, I got that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if `CanEdit` returns the correct value binary wise because due to the implementation of the compiler not only 1 is evaluated to True. But when negating that the compiler generates a `xor $01` which still returns True for any positive value except 1.

You can do that by evaluating this expression: Integer(TempBool). If that is any positive value except 1 then CanEdit returned something wrong.

Comment: `if Boolean(i) then` evaluates to True for every positive value of i where the least significant byte is not 0 because the compiler generates a `test al, al` followed by a `jz`.

Comment: I am not reasoning or relying on anything. I pointed out the fact that it currently is the case which might be the cause of the behavior observed by the OP.

Comment: Edited my question accordingly

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I did not realize that accepting the other answer would change acceptance of your answer. Apparently two answers, one leading to another is not possible. I have reverted the acceptance your answer

Comment: @StefanGlienke Did you mean least significant **bit**?

Comment: No, byte. The one byte registers (like `al`) are used for handling the Boolean type.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize:

The bug (`Boolean` contains an integer value different from `0` and `1`):

```
program Project9;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var B1, B3: Boolean;

begin
  ShortInt(B1):= -1;
  if B1 then Writeln('true')
        else Writeln('false');
  B3:= not B1;
  if B3 then Writeln('true')
        else Writeln('false');
  Readln;
end.
```

and the quick workaround (use `ByteBool`, `WordBool` or `LongBool`):

```
program Project9;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var B1, B3: ByteBool;

begin
  ShortInt(B1):= -1;
  if B1 then Writeln('true')
        else Writeln('false');
  B3:= not B1;
  if B3 then Writeln('true')
        else Writeln('false');
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the problem by not putting and invalid value into the boolean in the first place? Surely that's better than trying to workaround the actual problem.

Comment: God only knows what is the actual type returned by `CanEdit`.

Comment: Indeed. The thing is, no matter what it is, Delphi knows how to convert between all the possible things that correctly assignable to a Boolean.

Comment: Thank you, I update the question with code showing how the problem is cause in the 3rd party code